# Implementing efficient 512 bit integer type

Tags: java, performance, optimization, integer

I was asked to create 512 bit integer type to my RSA encryption algorithm. I started from the simplest bitwise operations `OR, AND, XOR, NOT`, afterwards using mentioned operations I implemented addition, subtraction etc.
Unfortunately after many tests, it's very slow on more than 128 bits.

I was surprised when I found site with RSA generation where it generated key using apparently javascript in several miliseconds. How I can improve my algorithm to get better efficiency ? Or better question would be: how proffesionals implement so big types with
such performance.

Here is my code:

```
    public class BigInt {

      public static final int    BYTE = 8;
      public static final int    DEFAULT_SIZE = 128;
      public final static BigInt ZERO = new BigInt(0);
      public final static BigInt ONE = new BigInt(1);
      public final static BigInt TEN = new BigInt(10);
      private boolean[] number;
      private Endianness endianness = Endianness.BIG_ENDIAN;

    public BigInt() {
        number = new boolean[DEFAULT_SIZE];
    }

    public BigInt(boolean[] number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public BigInt(int integerNumber) {
        this();
        boolean isNegative = false;
        if (integerNumber < 0) {
            isNegative = true;
            integerNumber = Math.abs(integerNumber);
        }
        for (int i = number.length - 1; i >= 1 && integerNumber >= 1; i--) {
            number[i] = integerNumber % 2 == 1;
            integerNumber >>= 1;
        }
        if (isNegative) {
            number = new BigInt(number).not().add(ONE).number;
        }
    }

    public BigInt(String binaryString) throws InvalidBinaryStringException {
        this();
        for (int i = binaryString.length() - 1, j = number.length - 1;
             i >= 0 && j >= 0; i--, j--) {
            if (binaryString.charAt(i) != '1' && binaryString.charAt(i) != '0') {
                throw new InvalidBinaryStringException(binaryString);
            }
            number[j] = (binaryString.charAt(i) - '0') == 1;
        }
    }

    public BigInt(BigInt copy) {
        this();
        System.arraycopy(copy.number, 0, number, 0, copy.number.length);
    }

    public BigInt add(BigInt component) {
        BigInt a, b;
        BigInt x = new BigInt(this);
        BigInt y = new BigInt(component);
        do {
            a = x.and(y);
            b = x.xor(y);
            x = a.shiftLeft(1);
            y = b;
        } while (!a.equals(ZERO));
        return b;
    }

    public BigInt sub(BigInt subtrahend) {
        return add(subtrahend.not().add(new BigInt(ONE)));
    }

    public BigInt mul(BigInt multiplier) {
        BigInt m = new BigInt(ONE), z = new BigInt(ZERO);
        BigInt x = new BigInt(this), y = new BigInt(multiplier);

        if (x.lessThen(ZERO)) {
            x = x.not().add(ONE);
            y = y.not().add(ONE);
        }

        while (x.greaterThenEqual(m) && !y.equals(ZERO)) {
            if (!x.and(m).equals(ZERO)) {
                z = y.add(z);
            }
            y = y.shiftLeft(1);
            m = m.shiftLeft(1);
        }
        return z;
    }

    public BigInt div(BigInt divisor) {
        BigInt mask = new BigInt(ONE);
        BigInt quotient = new BigInt(ZERO);

        BigInt numerator = new BigInt(this), denominator = new BigInt(divisor);

        if (numerator.lessThen(ZERO)) {
            numerator = numerator.not().add(ONE);
        }

        if (denominator.lessThen(ZERO)) {
            denominator = denominator.not().add(ONE);
        }

        while (denominator.lessThenEqual(numerator)) { // PROBLEM
            denominator = denominator.shiftLeft(1);
            mask = mask.shiftLeft(1);
        }

        while (mask.greaterThen(ONE)) {
            denominator = denominator.shiftRight(1);
            mask = mask.shiftRight(1);
            if (numerator.greaterThenEqual(denominator)) {
                numerator = numerator.sub(denominator);
                quotient = quotient.or(mask);
            }
        }

        if (number[0] != divisor.number[0]) {
            return quotient.not().add(ONE);
        }
        return quotient;
    }


    public BigInt mod(BigInt y) {
        // (x - y*(x/y))
        BigInt x = new BigInt(this);
        BigInt right = x.div(y);
        BigInt mid = y.mul(right);
        return x.sub(mid);
    }

    //completly inefficient for numbers larger than 32 bit
    @Deprecated
    public BigInt div2(BigInt divisor) {
        BigInt c = new BigInt(ZERO), sign = new BigInt(ZERO);
        BigInt x = new BigInt(this), y = new BigInt(divisor);
        if (x.lessThen(ZERO)) {
            x = x.not().add(ONE);
            sign = sign.xor(ONE);
        }

        if (y.lessThen(ZERO)) {
            y = y.not().add(ONE);
            sign = sign.xor(ONE);
        }

        if (!y.equals(ZERO)) {
            while (x.greaterThenEqual(y)) {
                x = x.sub(y);
                c = c.add(ONE);
            }
        }

        if (!sign.equals(ZERO)) {
            c = c.not().add(ONE);
        }
        return c;
    }

    //doesn't work for big numbers close to maximum bit
    @Deprecated
    public BigInt mod2(BigInt mod) {
        BigInt y = new BigInt(this);
        BigInt x = new BigInt(mod);

        BigInt p = new BigInt(x);

        if (y.lessThen(ZERO)) {
            y = y.not().add(ONE);
        }

        if (p.lessThen(ZERO)) {
            p = p.not().add(ONE);
            x = x.not().add(ONE);
        }

        while (p.lessThen(y)) {         //forever loop
            p = p.shiftLeft(1);
        }

        while (p.greaterThenEqual(x)) {
            if (y.greaterThenEqual(p)) {
                y = y.sub(p);
            }
            p = p.shiftRight(1);
        }

        if (number[0]) {
            y = y.not().add(ONE);
        }
        return y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (obj == this)
            return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof BigInt))
            return false;

        BigInt bigInt = (BigInt) obj;
        for (int i = 0; i < bigInt.number.length; i++) {
            if (number[i] != bigInt.number[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (!endianness.equals(bigInt.endianness)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean lessThen(BigInt num) {
        if (equals(num)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (number[0] && !num.number[0]) {
            return true;
        } else if (!number[0] && num.number[0]) {
            return false;
        }
        BigInt left = null, right = null;
        if (number[0]) {
            left = not().add(ONE);
            right = num.not().add(ONE);
        } else {
            left = this;
            right = num;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < number.length; i++) {
            if (left.number[i] != right.number[i]) {
                if (number[0]) {
                    return !(!left.number[i] && right.number[i]);
                } else {
                    return !left.number[i] && right.number[i];
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean lessThenEqual(BigInt num) {
        if (equals(num)) {
            return true;
        }
        return lessThen(num);
    }

    public boolean greaterThen(BigInt num) {
        return !lessThen(num);
    }

    public boolean greaterThenEqual(BigInt num) {
        if (equals(num)) {
            return true;
        }
        return greaterThen(num);
    }

    /**
     * BITWISE OPERATORS*
     */
    //logical bitwise shift lefts
    public BigInt shiftLeft(int n) {
        //IT WORKS BECAUSE NEW OBJECT IS SET TO 0;
        BigInt shifted = new BigInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < number.length - n; i++) {
            shifted.number[i] = number[i + n];
        }
        return shifted;
    }

    //logical bitwise shift right
    public BigInt shiftRight(int n) {
        BigInt shifted = new BigInt();
        for (int i = number.length - 1; i >= n; i--) {
            shifted.number[i] = number[i - n];
        }
        boolean sign = number[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            shifted.number[i] = sign;
        }
        return shifted;
    }

    //bitwise or |
    public BigInt or(BigInt num) {
        BigInt newInt = new BigInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
            newInt.number[i] = number[i] | num.number[i];
        }
        return newInt;
    }

    //bitwise and &
    public BigInt and(BigInt num) {
        BigInt newInt = new BigInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
            newInt.number[i] = number[i] & num.number[i];
        }
        return newInt;
    }

    //bitwise exclusive or ^
    public BigInt xor(BigInt num) {
        BigInt newInt = new BigInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
            newInt.number[i] = number[i] ^ num.number[i];
        }
        return newInt;
    }

    public BigInt not() {
        BigInt negate = new BigInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
           negate.number[i] = !number[i];
        }
        return negate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      /* StringBuilder binaryRepr = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : number) {
            binaryRepr.append(b);
        }*/

       String decRepr = "";
        BigInt copy = new BigInt(this);

        if (copy.lessThen(ZERO)) {
            copy = copy.not().add(ONE);
        }

        while (copy.greaterThenEqual(ONE)) {
            BigInt rem = copy.mod(TEN);
            copy = copy.div(TEN);
            decRepr = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(getDecimalRemainder(rem), 2)) + decRepr;
        }

        if (number[0]) {
            return "-" + decRepr;// + binaryRepr.toString();
        }
        return decRepr;// + binaryRepr.toString();
        //return binaryRepr.toString();
    }

    private String getDecimalRemainder(BigInt copy) {
        String decimalString = "";

        for (int i = copy.number.length - 1; i >= copy.number.length - 4; i--) {
            decimalString = (copy.number[i] ? "1" : "0") + decimalString;
        }
        return decimalString;
    }

    public String toBinaryString() {
        StringBuilder binaryString = new StringBuilder();
        boolean isFirstBit = false;
        for (boolean b: number) {
            if (b) {
                isFirstBit = true;
            }
            if (isFirstBit) {
                binaryString.append(b);
            }
        }
        return binaryString.toString();
    }

    public static BigInt nextBigInt(BigInt min, BigInt max) {
        BigInt pseudo = new BigInt();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 2; i < pseudo.number.length; i++) {
            pseudo.number[i] = rnd.nextBoolean();
        }
        return pseudo.mod(max).add(min);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String big = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < 126; i++) {
            big += "1";
        }
        StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
        System.out.println(new BigInt(big));
        System.out.println(stopWatch.elapsedTime());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you use [java.math.BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)?

Comment: If you're building new data types to do your encryption, you've probably gotten wrapped around the wrong axle.  Why not use something like BouncyCastle -- they've already found and fixed the first 10 years' worth of mistakes you're likely to make.

Comment: @gus Sounds more like someone asking them to re-invent the wheel for learning purposes. In the case of assignments, anything goes.

Comment: @MxyL Yes, it's for learning purposes. Therefore I don't use any built-in type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of the `boolean[]` use an `int[]` to hold the bits of your number. This way you can implement most operations much faster, operating on say 30 bits at once instead of just 1.

You can keep the lowest 30 bits in array element 0 the next 30 bits in array element 1 and so on. It is straight forward to implement the logical operations (&, |, ^) with this structure.

For the arithmetic operations you have to keep track of carry bits. For example after adding the two array elements 0, if the result is larger than 30 bits, clear the overflow bit and add 1 to the sum of the array elements 1.

Multiplication can be done by using `long`: the product of two `int` values always fits into a `long`. Use a method like multiplying two decimal numbers by hand. Just use 30 bit digits instead of the digits 0-9.

More sophisticated multiplication methods like karatsuba don't pay off for numbers that are only 512 bits long.

While it is fun to implement and optimize these operations, it is also very easy to have subtle bugs in the implementation. So if you do that for production code be sure to write lots of unit tests. It may be better to use a well tested third party implementation instead of doing it on your own.

Comment: Well, why not `long[]`? 8 `long`s would be 512 bits.

Comment: @In the beggining it was `byte[]` array, but then I changed it to boolean - I thought it would be improvement, however it wasn't. Anyway, according to your answer, can you be more precise ? I'm not sure how I could do something like this.

Comment: @dcsohl But how would I manage all operations ? The same way as it was ? I'm not sure I understand the idea of array of ints or longs.

Comment: @dcsohl multiplication is a bit easier by using `int` instead of `long`.

Comment: @Henry Thank you, I'm beginning to understand what you mean. However, what makes me curious is why use only 30 bits of int and not 32 ? I can see this structure as array of ints as you said. `int[] number;`, and I can do all bitwise operations such like `number[i] &= number2[i]`, but these 30 bits confuses me a bit. Can you explain me your reasoning ?

Comment: @ashur it makes it a bit easier to detect overflow. If you use 32 bits it is more difficult to determine if the result fits into 32 bits as well or if there was a carry. Moreover, int is signed in Java while our operations should work with unsigned quantities. So, it just reduces code complexity and therefore makes it more likely to avoid bugs.

Comment: @ashur: I'd bet that using 30 bits rather than 32 is not a good idea. The reasoning by Henry is fine, but 30 bits per `int` means  redundancy or unused bits and each of them may cause enough problems. There's actually no problem with `int`s being signed as the result of add/sub are the same as for unsigned (and you need some special handling for mul/div anyway). For learning, doing it yourself is good but I'd recommend to look at the existing sources too.

Comment: Overflow can be easily detected, even when using all 32 bits in an int (through simple boolean operations). When an unsigned int is desired, the signed primitive int can also double for that - it just requires attention on the programmers side (on the binary level both are the same, just the interpretation is different).

Comment: @maaartinus I did not say it is impossible to operate with all 32 bits. But it adds some special cases to take care of.

Comment: @Henry: I'm just saying that using fewer bits has some problems too and that I'd go for 32. Either way it's doable and I'd prefer the more efficient solution.